# Placement of 私 in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Are both options grammatically correct?
家族の中で私が一番背が高いです。
私は家族の中で一番背が高いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all of the following are grammatical (yours are 1 and 3).

1. 家族の中で私が一番背が高いです。
2. 私が家族の中で一番背が高いです。
3. 私は家族の中で一番背が高いです。
4. 家族の中で私は一番背が高いです。

I don't feel any difference between 1 and 2, but 4 may be slightly less idiomatic than 3. A rough idea is that it's better to put the topic first.

---

The following question will help:

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/45489)